# Handling variables across the flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables

I am refactoring an old app I wrote a few years ago. In the original app I used global variables to access different data across the app such as permissions and IDs.

I know globals are not the best way of providing access to data across the app so I am asking what is the best way. Is it service classes or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use libraries such as "**provider**" or "**get**" and handle the variables in their classes, it's the best way to save the variables

These are the libraries:

provider: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

get: https://pub.dev/packages/get

there is another libraries such as **block**, *etc*...